# Cannot set session ajax using jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

i want to add a value to a session array when ever i click a button on my form. i tried to achieve this using jquery onclick, ajax and jquery. but it doesnt seem to set a variable or return anything.

in my main.php i have

```
<form id="sessy">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $("#sessy").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "session.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(){
                // Do what you want to do when the session has been updated
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
</script>

<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];

?>
```

and in my session.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'][] = $_POST['name'];
?>
```

and i am calling jQuery.js at the bottom of the page.

it gives me below, where line 23 is the part where i am trying to echo the session variable.

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in ....main.php on line 23
```

and i try print_r($_SESSION); instead of echo i get just "Array ( )"

Comment: add `if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) { $_SESSION['name'] = []; }` before `$_SESSION['name'][] = $_POST['name'];`

Comment: `session_start();` must be used before any content are writed to the output, the result will not be shown after the submit because the page dont reload, and  `$_SESSION['name']` is an array so `echo $_SESSION['name'];` is wrong and you should check before if key 'name' is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a `form` is you submit with ajax.
And `submit` is a reserved keyword that you shouldn't use as an `id`, `class` or a `name`.
It has a tendency to bug...

Try this as your main.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sessy">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
    $("#sessy .btn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "session.php",
            data: $("#sessy #name"),
            success: function(data){
                // Do what you want to do when the session has been updated
                $("#result").html("<h2>Name «"+data+"» is in session.</h2>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And your session.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

Comment: this adds session and echos them. i want the values to be added to an array. how can i modify this to do so?

Comment: It sets the $_SESSION, wich is an array, with the key `name` = inputed value sent via ajax. This session array is unique to this user. I don't get what you really want to do here. Create an array of many names ?

Comment: currently, when i enter a new name in the field and submit, it gets overwritten . thus its and array of only one Array ( [name] => dwdwdwd ). but i want is for example Array ( [name1] => dwdwdwd, [name2] => jdjdjdwd,  )

Comment: i want to push any new value into the array

Comment: $_SESSION['names'][] = $_POST['name']; did the trick. thank you